# How can I speed up this PostgreSQL UPDATE FROM sql query? It currently takes days to finish running

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

How can I speed up the PostgreSQL UPDATE FROM sql query below? It currently takes days to finish running.

```
UPDATE import_parts ip
SET part_part_id = pp.id
FROM parts.part_parts pp
WHERE pp.upc = ip.upc
AND (ip.status is null or ip.status != '6');
```

And why does it takes days to run in the first place?

Most of the time, I manually kill the query because it takes too long to run like more than 24 hours. Last time it successfully finished running, it took almost 38 hours.

`import_parts` table has `971971` rows

`parts.part_parts` table has `2196357` rows

`parts.part_parts` table has an index on `upc` and `id` is the primary key of the table.

I already tried running `VACUUM ANALYZE` on `import_parts` table and `parts.part_parts` table before the update query above runs but the query still takes too long to run, so I manually killed it after 30 minutes. I'm hoping to be able to run the query in under 30 minutes.

Here's the result of EXPLAIN when I run the query after running `VACUUM ANALYZE` on `import_parts` table and `parts.part_parts` table:

[image: result of EXPLAIN]

UPDATE 1:

I also tried setting `enable_nestloop` to off: `SET enable_nestloop TO off`

But the query still takes too long to run so I manually killed it. Here's the result of `EXPLAIN` when enable_nestloop is turned off:

[image: result of EXPLAIN when nestloop is turned off]

UPDATE 2:

Here's the result of EXPLAIN when using the query suggested by Abelisto on his answer to this post:

[image: result of Explain using the suggested query of Abelisto]

When I actually run the query though, I'm encountering this error:

`ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

I'm still figuring out how to fix the error.

Comment: `rows=36404028150` - something wrong with the logic. 36 billions of updates can not be fast (at least on the regular hardware)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, try to rewrite your query like

```
UPDATE import_parts ip
SET part_part_id = (
  SELECT pp.id
  FROM parts.part_parts pp
  WHERE pp.upc = ip.upc)
WHERE status is null or status != '6';
```

Obviously it raises something like to

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Fix it using additionally conditions (subquery should to return exactly one or zero row for each row in the target table)

Comment: Thank you for answering. The result of EXPLAIN looks more promising now I think. I updated my post to provide some updates. I'm still figuring out how to fix this error: `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. I think I'll be able to fix it by making sure there are no 2 or more rows on `import_parts` table that has the same upc and there are no 2 or more rows on `parts.part_parts` table with the same upc? Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @JohnKenn See my answer: "subquery should to return exactly one row for each row in the target table". So for `pp.upc = ip.upc` condition it should to be [one-to-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)) or many-to-one relation. Agree, it is not the case to update the single row in the target table several times.

Comment: Ok. So the error means we have 2 or more rows on `parts.part_parts` table that has the same values for `upc`. I'll check if it's possible for us to make the upc field unique. If not, I'll think of another way on how to fix the error.

Comment: @JohnKenn Exactly. You need to decide what value should be assigned to `part_part_id`

Comment: BTW, why did the results of EXPLAIN or query plan changed after rewriting the original sql query to your suggested sql query?

Answer (score 1):

From what you say, it seems that `upc` is not unique in `parts_parts`.  Try running this:

```
select upc, count(*)
from parts.parts_parts pp
group by upc
having count(*) > 1;
```

These duplicates are probably causing the performance problems.  You could get around this by arbitrarily choosing a value, such as:

```
UPDATE import_parts ip
  SET part_part_id = pp.id
  FROM (SELECT pp.upc, MIN(pp.id) as id
        FROM parts.part_parts pp
        GROUP BY pp.upc
       ) pp
  WHERE pp.upc = ip.upc AND (ip.status is null or ip.status <> '6');
```

Comment: `MIN(pp.id)` sounds like "let's assign something random just to avoid the error"

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try your suggested query and provide an update after. FYI, I just found out that there are almost 600k rows from `parts.part_parts` table that has a `null` value on the `upc` field.

Comment: @JohnKenn . . . You should fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an index with in import_parts with columns: upc,status.
2. I will recomend you to split in two sentences:

I do't know your status, but i suppose you have status: null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

```
UPDATE import_parts ip
SET part_part_id = pp.id
FROM parts.part_parts pp
WHERE pp.upc = ip.upc
AND ip.status is null
;

UPDATE import_parts ip
SET part_part_id = pp.id
FROM parts.part_parts pp
WHERE pp.upc = ip.upc
AND ip.status IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)
;
```

3. Of course you need to change 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 for your values(different from 6)
4. I also like the answer of @Gordon Linoff, but it depends of how many rows do you have by upc